# How do I affect the entirety of an array?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have an array I am using to hold movie clips, and I'd like to be able to change all of them at once using the array. Now, I can do it using `array[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8...].changestuff` but with 60 or so movieclips, it gets unwieldy. Is there a simpler way to go through the entire array and apply the changes to each movieclip stored within?

Comment: Try a for loop. http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/loops/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an array of MovieClips something like this:

```
var a:Array = new Array;
for ( var j:int = 0; j < 10; j++ )
    a[j] = new MovieClip;
```

You have 3 ways of looping through it and affecting all the MovieClips inside it. The first is the basic for loop:

```
var len:int = a.length;
for ( var i:int = 0; i < len; i++ )
{
    var mc:MovieClip = a[i];
    trace( mc );
}
```

The basic for loop is the quickest way of looping through an array. You just need to find the MovieClip at the specific index using the brackets operator. `a[i]` will return the MovieClip at the current index (e.g. `a[0]` will return the MovieClip at the start of the array, `a[1]` the next one, etc).

You can also do a for..each:

```
for each( var mc:MovieClip in a )
    trace( mc );
```

For..each loops are slightly slower than a normal for loop, but has the added benefit of having access to the object directly, already casted. It can be quite convenient

And finally use the `forEach()` method:

```
a.forEach( this._loopFunc );

private function _loopFunc( mc:MovieClip, index:int, a:Array ):void
{
    trace( mc + " is at index " + index + " in array " + a );
}
```

I've never really seen `forEach()` used anywhere, but you might find it useful. For the callback, you need to declare 3 parameters, the object, the index, and the array itself.

You can find more info at the Array documentation: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html

Comment: As a side note: The array constructor is only supposed to be used for fixed length arrays: new Array(int); All other times, the adobe standard is var arr:Array = []

Comment: This is the info I needed, thank you very much. I always check the adobe documentation before consulting anywhere else, but it's more syntactical than explanatory in most cases.

Comment: Don't forget to check out the `Vector` class: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Vector.html - it's like an Array, but only for one type of object. It's much smaller and faster than Array. To create a `Vector` for just MovieClips, it's: `var v:Vector.<MovieClip> = new Vector.<MovieClip>(len, true);` (where `len` is if you want to create a `Vector` of a specific length, and `true` is if you want it to be fixed length (i.e. can't add or remove elements, but you gain in speed))

Comment: @cwallenpoole - Array doesn't have a fixed length. `new Array(5)` will create an Array with 5 elements, but you can still add elements as you want. See the examples here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#Array2()

Comment: never had use for those. Either way [] is preferred constructor

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use a:

```
for(var item in collection) { ... }
```

Not listed in the link.

Comment: I can do a for loop, but I don't know how to convert an int into a call number for an array. I do `array.length-i`, i being the for loop counter, and have an int that I can work with, but have no idea how to turn the int of 34 into `array[34]`.

Comment: Pardon my stupidity. I was way over thinking it, all I really had to do was `array[i]` after the for loop, no need for another comparison to the length once it's used as the measuring stick for ending the for loop.

Answer (score -1):

The best way to manipulate an entire array at once is using the map method.

A [mapping](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/Array.html#map%28%29) example from the Adobe LiveDocs

```
    public function arrayMap() {
        var arr:Array = new Array("one", "two", "Three");
        trace(arr); // one,two,Three

        var upperArr:Array = arr.map(toUpper);
        trace(upperArr); // ONE,TWO,THREE
    }

    private function toUpper(element:*, index:int, arr:Array):String {
        return String(element).toUpperCase();
    }
```

In your case you'd just write a callback method that manipulates your movieclips however necessary and returns a MovieClip instead of String.

Comment: sorry, `Array.map()` is a terrible way to loop through and call a function on each one. From the docs: "Executes a function on each item in an array, and *constructs a new array of items corresponding to the results of the function on each item in the original array*." At best this is needless allocation, at worst it's a huge memory/speed drain